# Mouse cursor change once ENTER pressed

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextfield, keyboard-events

I have an image here to explain my query
[image]

As you can see in the image I have many text fields,right now the cursor is on the text field(the cursor could be on any textfield).
As you can 3 out of the last 4 fields are disabled,once I press the enter those get enabled.This everything works fine.
My query is once I press enter how do I move my cursor to the position down there(**marked in red**)?
This is the small snippet of code for the once enter key pressed.

```
((JPanel)frame.getContentPane()).getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "doSomething");
        ((JPanel)frame.getContentPane()).getActionMap ().put("doSomething", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("profit");
                // disabledField.setEnabled(true);
                textbox9.setEnabled(true);
                textbox10.setEnabled(true);
                textbox11.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request focus by using [`JComponent#requestFocusInWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29)

For example...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("profit");
    // disabledField.setEnabled(true);
    textbox9.setEnabled(true);
    textbox10.setEnabled(true);
    textbox11.setEnabled(true);
    textbox9.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Take a look at [How to use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) for more details